# Expected function body after function declarator

Tags: c++

Not sure where the error is persisting here, having trouble including an if statement in my for loop

```
 bool operator<=(string a, const Zoo& z)
        // Pre: none
        // Post: returns true if animal a is in Zoo z.
        //       the owner does not count as an animal.

          for ( int i=0; i< z.count-1; i++ ) {

            if (z.cage[z.count-1] == a){
              return true;
            }

             else {
               return false;
           }
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need to copy the string?

Comment: Personally `operator <=` would not be a logical choice for "check if animal a is in Zoo" for me

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: There's much else wrong with that function - you probably want to be looking in `z.cage[i]` each iteration, and not returning `false` until after the loop.  And `operator<=` seems like a poor choice of name for what you're doing.

Answer (score 19):

You forgot to put a bracket `{` at the beginning of your function body.